# Tags not appearing in "Add New Post" Page

Tags: posts, tags

I'm working on a mag website. I'm using `Tags` to group some content.
For this I have added all the required tags from the **Tags** section under **Posts**.
But When I go to `Posts -> Add New`, the Tags panel displays nothing.

[image]

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-get_the_tag-to-label-post-titles

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Screen Options** on the top right and make sure you checked **Tags**.